# How to add a custom block on Print module?

Tags: 7, nodes, files

I'm using the [Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module. I wonder if there is a way to print a custom block on the `print.tpl.php`. Because I want to print a node but that node has its own custom blocks that is rendered on its `.tpl`. I want the PDF of the Print module to also get all those blocks on the display.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module. It allows you to add the block as a field in the "Manage display" tab of your content type. You can then place it wherever you want on your node page.

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7
>   only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. Will try it and report back if its good. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @JoshuaAbellare. Ya sure. I hope your issue might be solved by using this module.

Comment: It worked! Thanks @NishantP! Although I still have a problem, some of my blocks has a contextual filter "Content ID from URL" and doesn't display on the PDF display. I think because the PDF doesn't have a NID not like a node, is there a way around this? Hope you can help.